# Copy row from sheet 1 to sheet 2 based on row number

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i want to be able to enter a row number in "PrintSheet" cell G15 and copy the specified numbered row from "Log" to row 40 on "PrintSheet", I have tried this and lots of other code but none does what Ii need, this one keeps stopping at:

`Sheets(“Log”).Rows(15).EntireRow.Copy`

but not sure why

***My Code***

```
Sub GetOrder()
    Dim val As Integer

    val = Sheets("PrintSheet").Range("G15")

    Sheets(“Log”).Rows(15).EntireRow.Copy

    Sheets("PrintSheet").Range("A40").Select
    Sheets(“PrintSheet”).Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using `”` and not `"`.

Second, Copy >> Paste is a 1 line command, and there's no need to `Select` the range before you paste in it.

**Third**, and an answer why you are getting the error you asked in your post,  to copy an entire row you can either use:

```
Sheets("Log").Rows(15).Copy
```

or

```
Sheets("Log").Range("A15").EntireRow.Copy
```

And last, you need to use the row value from cell "G15" `val` inside your copy, so it should be `Sheets("Log").Rows(val).Copy`.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetOrder()

    Dim val As Long

    val = Sheets("PrintSheet").Range("G15").Value

    ' copy >> paste is 1-line command
    Sheets("Log").Rows(val).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PrintSheet").Range("A40")

End Sub
```

Comment: Superb this has been driving me nuts for days.